# Python - Check if a word "Is Isogram"

Tags: python

I could look up the right answer, but I am just so certain I am correct as I get this to pass all my tests in IDLE, but on my online course it only partially passes - any reason why?

```
def is_isogram(txt):
    if len(list(txt)) == len(set(txt)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: uppercase/lowercase?

Answer (score 1):

It might be that you aren't accounting for a string with upper ***and*** lowercase letters. Using either `str.upper` or `str.lower` might be the solution. If that is the case, something like this could do it in one pass.

```
def is_isogram(txt):
    seen = set()
    for char in txt.lower():
        if char in seen:
            return False
        seen.add(char)
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

Mostly it is failing due to case sensitive issue. Why don't you add *lower()* to your code and try it:

```
def is_isogram(txt):
    if len(list(txt.lower())) == len(set(txt.lower())):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

the below made me pass my quiz, I did need to account for lower/upper!

```
def is_isogram(txt):
    txt = txt.lower()
    if len(list(txt)) == len(set(txt)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```